# Number of rounds required to decide a "more swiss" competition given P players and L lives

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

In a regular Swiss tournament, as described in a previous post ([How many rounds are required in a "Swiss tournament sorting algorithm"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071246/how-many-rounds-are-required-in-a-swiss-tournament-sorting-algorithm)), all players stay in the competition until the last round. This can cause issues because players who are doing badly have no real hope of winning the competition and lose interest, often dropping out and spoiling the tournament for others.

A "more Swiss" tournament (https://www.moreswiss.com) combines a regular Swiss with an elimination element, such that players are removed from the competition after a certain number of losses (typically 3).

In this type of tournament the number of rounds is not fixed, because it can happen that two players make it to the "final" unbeaten but then have to play each other repeatedly until one of them accrues 3 losses, for example.

There are also complexities in some rounds because of byes given. If a round has an odd number of players the weakest player (according to current standings) is given a bye through to the next round.

I would like to find a formula that gives the maximum number of rounds that will be required given the number of players P and the number of lives allowed L. The number of players does not have to be a power of 2 (as is the case for many elimination style tournaments). The idea is that any number of players can enter.

There is a handy bit of maths for the proportion of players remaining after N rounds in a triple elimination here: https://rkallos.com/blog/2019/12/22/a-bit-of-math-triple-elimination-tournament. I'm after a discreet formula for the minimum N that guarantees there is only one player remaining, and generalised to any number of lives.

As an illustration, below is a random tournament generated for P=20 and L=3. You can see that in some rounds there are byes given and also that some players must play each other more than once, in the later rounds.

````
    1 # easydate (0)              v      ablearea (1)                        # 
    1 # dumbcost (0)              v      backarmy (1)                        # 
    1 # barebaby (0)              v      dullclub (1)                        # 
    1 # bassback (0)              v      dualcity (1)                        # 
    1 # blueball (0)              v      deepcash (1)                        # 
    1 # dearcase (0)              v      boldband (1)                        # 
    1 # busybank (0)              v      deafcare (1)                        # 
    1 # calmbase (0)              v      deadcard (1)                        # 
    1 # coldbill (0)              v      darkcall (1)                        # 
    1 # coolbody (0)              v      dampbook (1)                        # 
    
    bassback                1    1    0    0    5    0
    blueball                1    1    0    0    5    0
    coldbill                1    1    0    0    5    0
    dumbcost                1    1    0    0    4    0
    barebaby                1    1    0    0    4    0
    calmbase                1    1    0    0    4    0
    easydate                1    1    0    0    2    0
    dearcase                1    1    0    0    2    0
    busybank                1    1    0    0    2    0
    coolbody                1    1    0    0    2    0
    ablearea                1    0    0    0   -2    0
    boldband                1    0    0    0   -2    0
    deafcare                1    0    0    0   -2    0
    dampbook                1    0    0    0   -2    0
    backarmy                1    0    0    0   -4    0
    dullclub                1    0    0    0   -4    0
    deadcard                1    0    0    0   -4    0
    dualcity                1    0    0    0   -5    0
    deepcash                1    0    0    0   -5    0
    darkcall                1    0    0    0   -5    0
    
    2 # bassback (0)              v      blueball (1)                        # 
    2 # dumbcost (0)              v      coldbill (1)                        # 
    2 # barebaby (0)              v      calmbase (1)                        # 
    2 # easydate (0)              v      dearcase (1)                        # 
    2 # busybank (0)              v      coolbody (1)                        # 
    2 # ablearea (1)              v      boldband (2)                        # 
    2 # dampbook (1)              v      deafcare (2)                        # 
    2 # dullclub (1)              v      backarmy (2)                        # 
    2 # deadcard (1)              v      dualcity (2)                        # 
    2 # deepcash (1)              v      darkcall (2)                        # 
    
    bassback                2    2    0    0    9    0
    dumbcost                2    2    0    0    6    0
    barebaby                2    2    0    0    6    0
    busybank                2    2    0    0    5    0
    easydate                2    2    0    0    3    0
    calmbase                2    1    1    0    2    0
    blueball                2    1    1    0    1    0
    coolbody                2    1    1    0   -1    0
    ablearea                2    1    0    0    3    0
    coldbill                2    1    0    0    3    0
    dampbook                2    1    0    0    2    0
    dearcase                2    1    0    0    1    0
    deepcash                2    1    0    0    0    0
    dullclub                2    1    0    0   -1    0
    deadcard                2    1    0    0   -1    0
    deafcare                2    0    0    0   -6    0
    backarmy                2    0    0    0   -7    0
    boldband                2    0    0    0   -7    0
    dualcity                2    0    0    0   -8    0
    darkcall                2    0    0    0  -10    0
    
    3 # bassback (0)              v      dumbcost (1)                        # 
    3 # barebaby (0)              v      busybank (1)                        # 
    3 # calmbase (1)              v      easydate (1)                        # 
    3 # blueball (1)              v      coolbody (2)                        # 
    3 # coldbill (1)              v      ablearea (2)                        # 
    3 # dampbook (1)              v      dearcase (2)                        # 
    3 # deepcash (1)              v      dullclub (2)                        # 
    3 # deadcard (1)              v      deafcare (3-eliminated)             # 
    3 # boldband (2)              v      backarmy (3-eliminated)             # 
    3 # dualcity (2)              v      darkcall (3-eliminated)             # 
    
    bassback                3    3    0    2   10    0
    barebaby                3    3    0    2    8    0
    calmbase                3    2    2    2    6    0
    blueball                3    2    1    2    6    0
    dumbcost                3    2    1    2    5    0
    coldbill                3    2    0    1    7    0
    dampbook                3    2    0    1    6    0
    deepcash                3    2    0    1    5    0
    busybank                3    2    0    1    3    0
    deadcard                3    2    0    1    3    0
    easydate                3    2    0    1   -1    0
    ablearea                3    1    1    2   -1    0
    dearcase                3    1    1    2   -3    0
    dualcity                3    1    0    2   -5    0
    dullclub                3    1    0    2   -6    0
    coolbody                3    1    0    2   -6    0
    boldband                3    1    0    1   -6    0
    
    4 # boldband (2)              v      *bye*                               # 
    4 # barebaby (0)              v      bassback (1)                        # 
    4 # blueball (1)              v      calmbase (2)                        # 
    4 # dumbcost (1)              v      dampbook (2)                        # 
    4 # deepcash (1)              v      coldbill (2)                        # 
    4 # busybank (1)              v      deadcard (2)                        # 
    4 # easydate (1)              v      dualcity (3-eliminated)             # 
    4 # dearcase (2)              v      ablearea (3-eliminated)             # 
    4 # coolbody (2)              v      dullclub (3-eliminated)             # 
    
    barebaby                4    4    0    5    9    0
    bassback                4    3    2    6    9    0
    blueball                4    3    1    5    9    0
    dumbcost                4    3    0    4   10    0
    busybank                4    3    0    4    4    0
    deepcash                4    3    0    3    7    0
    easydate                4    3    0    3    2    0
    calmbase                4    2    1    6    3    0
    coolbody                4    2    1    5   -4    0
    dearcase                4    2    1    4    2    0
    dampbook                4    2    1    4    1    0
    coldbill                4    2    0    4    5    0
    deadcard                4    2    0    3    2    0
    boldband                4    2    0    1   -7    0
    
    5 # barebaby (0)              v      blueball (2)                        # 
    5 # bassback (1)              v      busybank (2)                        # 
    5 # dumbcost (1)              v      deepcash (2)                        # 
    5 # coolbody (2)              v      easydate (2)                        # 
    5 # dearcase (2)              v      calmbase (3-eliminated)             # 
    5 # coldbill (2)              v      dampbook (3-eliminated)             # 
    5 # deadcard (2)              v      boldband (3-eliminated)             # 
    
    barebaby                5    5    0    8   12    0
    bassback                5    4    1   10   14    0
    dumbcost                5    4    0    8   11    0
    blueball                5    3    2   10    6    0
    busybank                5    3    2   10   -1    0
    coolbody                5    3    1    8    0    0
    deepcash                5    3    1    7    6    0
    easydate                5    3    1    6   -2    0
    coldbill                5    3    0    6    6    0
    dearcase                5    3    0    6    3    0
    deadcard                5    3    0    5    3    0
    
    6 # deadcard (2)              v      *bye*                               # 
    6 # barebaby (0)              v      dumbcost (2)                        # 
    6 # bassback (1)              v      coolbody (3-eliminated)             # 
    6 # busybank (2)              v      blueball (3-eliminated)             # 
    6 # deepcash (2)              v      easydate (3-eliminated)             # 
    6 # dearcase (2)              v      coldbill (3-eliminated)             # 
    
    barebaby                6    6    0   13   15    0
    bassback                6    5    0   14   18    0
    busybank                6    4    1   15    4    0
    dumbcost                6    4    1   14    8    0
    deepcash                6    4    0   10    9    0
    dearcase                6    4    0    9    8    0
    deadcard                6    4    0    5    2    0
    
    7 # dearcase (2)              v      *bye*                               # 
    7 # deepcash (2)              v      barebaby (1)                        # 
    7 # bassback (1)              v      deadcard (3-eliminated)             # 
    7 # dumbcost (2)              v      busybank (3-eliminated)             # 
    
    barebaby                7    6    1   19   10    0
    bassback                7    6    0   19   20    0
    dumbcost                7    5    1   20   10    0
    deepcash                7    5    0   15   14    0
    dearcase                7    5    0    9    7    0
    
    8 # deepcash (2)              v      *bye*                               # 
    8 # bassback (1)              v      barebaby (2)                        # P rnd4
    8 # dumbcost (2)              v      dearcase (3-eliminated)             # 
    
    bassback                8    7    0   20   21    0
    dumbcost                8    6    1   26   14    0
    barebaby                8    6    1   21    9    0
    deepcash                8    6    1   16   16    0
    
    9 # dumbcost (2)              v      bassback (2)                        # P rnd3
    9 # barebaby (2)              v      deepcash (3-eliminated)             # P rnd7
    
    barebaby                9    7    2   22   10    0
    bassback                9    7    2   21   20    0
    dumbcost                9    7    1   27   15    0
    
    10 # dumbcost (2)              v      *bye*                               # 
    10 # barebaby (2)              v      bassback (3-eliminated)             # P rnd4,rnd8
    
    barebaby               10    8    1   22   15    0
    dumbcost               10    8    0   27   19    0
    
    11 # barebaby (2)              v      dumbcost (3-eliminated)             # P rnd6
    
    barebaby               11    9    0   22   16    0
```
````